# Pass everything to one location nginx

Tags: php, linux, nginx, url-rewriting

I want to pass all traffic to one `.php` file, tried this but not working. I'm using `nginx 1.10.0`

Here is output of `nginx -V` :

> nginx version: nginx/1.10.0 (Ubuntu)
>   built with OpenSSL 1.0.2g-fips  1 Mar 2016
>   TLS SNI support enabled
>   configure arguments: --with-cc-opt='-g -O2 -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2' --with-ld-opt='-Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -fPIE -pie -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now' --prefix=/usr/share/nginx --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --lock-path=/var/lock/nginx.lock --pid-path=/run/nginx.pid --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/body --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/fastcgi --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/proxy --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/scgi --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/uwsgi --with-debug --with-pcre-jit --with-ipv6 --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_auth_request_module --with-http_addition_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_flv_module --with-http_geoip_module --with-http_gunzip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_image_filter_module --with-http_mp4_module --with-http_perl_module --with-http_random_index_module --with-http_secure_link_module --with-http_v2_module --with-http_sub_module --with-http_xslt_module --with-mail --with-mail_ssl_module --with-stream --with-stream_ssl_module --with-threads --add-module=/build/nginx-wAi2qr/nginx-1.10.0/debian/modules/headers-more-nginx-module --add-module=/build/nginx-wAi2qr/nginx-1.10.0/debian/modules/nginx-auth-pam --add-module=/build/nginx-wAi2qr/nginx-1.10.0/debian/modules/nginx-cache-purge --add-module=/build/nginx-wAi2qr/nginx-1.10.0/debian/modules/nginx-dav-ext-module --add-module=/build/nginx-wAi2qr/nginx-1.10.0/debian/modules/nginx-development-kit --add-module=/build/nginx-wAi2qr/nginx-1.10.0/debian/modules/nginx-echo --add-module=/build/nginx-wAi2qr/nginx-1.10.0/debian/modules/ngx-fancyindex --add-module=/build/nginx-wAi2qr/nginx-1.10.0/debian/modules/nginx-http-push --add-module=/build/nginx-wAi2qr/nginx-1.10.0/debian/modules/nginx-lua --add-module=/build/nginx-wAi2qr/nginx-1.10.0/debian/modules/nginx-upload-progress --add-module=/build/nginx-wAi2qr/nginx-1.10.0/debian/modules/nginx-upstream-fair --add-module=/build/nginx-wAi2qr/nginx-1.10.0/debian/modules/ngx_http_substitutions_filter_module

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;

    server_name _;

    location / {

        include /etc/nginx/snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;

        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /location/to/php/cache.php;       
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;

    }


    # Set maximum expire to all static files

    location ~* ^.+\.(ogg|ogv|svg|svgz|eot|otf|woff|mp4|ttf|rss|atom|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|ppt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf)$ {
        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
        expires max;
    }

} # server
```

Comment: What exactly do you expect to achieve? Do you want to pass execution flow into cache.php for every request (even for static files)? What's in your cache.php? What's in nginx logs? What kind of error do you have now?

Answer (score 0):

Try following configuration:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;

    server_name _;

    root /location/to/php;
    index cache.php;

    location / {
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ /cache.php?requestedPath=$1 break;
        include /etc/nginx/snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }


    # Set maximum expire to all static files

    location ~* ^.+\.(ogg|ogv|svg|svgz|eot|otf|woff|mp4|ttf|rss|atom|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|zip|t    gz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|ppt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf)$ {
        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
        expires max;
    }

} # server
```

Then you can use `requestedPath` from GET params in your `cache.php`.

But this config will not redirect execution flow to PHP for static files. If you want to process images and other static files in your `cache.php` you should add add to second `location` block the same rows as in first one.